# cast to base-type not supported for generic method

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have an interface `IGenericOrder` as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    interface IGenericOrder<T> where T : new()
    {
        Func<T, int> GetStatement(string name);
    }


    public class GenericOrder<T> : IGenericOrder<T> where T : new()
    {
        public Func<T, int> GetStatement(string name)
        {
            return (T) => 4;
        }    
    }
}
```

Now when I create an instance of that class and cast it back to `IGenericOrder<object>`

```
var sorter = (IGenericOrder<object>) new GenericOrder<Foo>();
```

I get Exception:

> InvalidCastException: The instance of type `GenericOrder<Foo>` cannot be cast to `IGenericOrder<object>`

Which seems clear as the Interface `IGenericOrder` is not covariant. However if I make the interface covariant (`interface  IGenericOrder<out T>`) I get a compiler-error:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on `IGenericOrder<T>.GetStatement(string)`. 'T' is covariant.

As I read from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) covariance can only used when

> [the generic type parameter] is used only as a method return type and is not used as a type of formal method parameters.

Does this mean I cannot use co-/contravariance for methods that themselfes return generic instances?

I am using .Net 4.5

Comment: Yes. I mean, you have all the information you need already, and you interpreted it correctly. It even makes sense. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Well, that´s what the errors say to me, but I do not fully understand the intense of this. What exactly makes sense from your point of view?

Comment: Just think about it - you're returning a function that takes an argument of type `T`. If you were allowed to cast the interface to `IGenericOrder<object>`, it would return a function that takes an argument of type `object`. Not all `T`s are also `object`s - you broke type safety. On the other hand, you can make `T` *contra*-variant - it's valid to pass a descendant instead of a parent class as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `T` as the first type parameter of `Func`, so the only valid mode is *contravariance* because the `T` represents the type of the function's parameter. What you are trying to achieve with your cast is unsafe: you are saying "Here's a function which takes a `Foo` as a parameter. Please treat this as a function which takes any `object` as a parameter." If instead you had a `Func<int, T>`, you could use covariance, because a function that returns a `Foo` can also be viewed as a function that returns an `object`.

Comment: That makes sense... somehow. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is going on look at the definition of [`Func<T,TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(
    T arg
)
```

As you can see, its first type parameter `T` is an `in` parameter. Therefore, you cannot use an `out` parameter as `Func`'s first type argument. The second type parameter `TResult` is `out`, so using `T` as `TResult` would work:

```
interface IGenericOrder<out T> where T : new() {
    Func<int,T> GetStatement(string name);
}

public class GenericOrder<T> : IGenericOrder<T> where T : new() {
    public Func<int,T> GetStatement(string name) {
        return (x) => default(T);
    }    
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/yPmfks)

Comment: I see, with the signature of `Func` this becomes obvious. Thank you for pointing that out